# how to split a pandas row into several rows and process some of their values?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a function that splits a pandas row into several rows AND updates some values at a particular column.

The problem would look like this;

```
   Id  Values
 0  A    2000
 1  B     600
```

and the expected results after splitting only those **Ids** with a **Value** larger than **800** into **smaller quantities**. That would be;

```
  Id  Values
0  A     800
1  A     800
2  A     400
3  B     600
```

The logic to split the values is not so relevant. For example;

```
2000 = 800 + 800 + 400
2000 = 700 + 700 + 600
```

any ideas on how to tack this problem?

Comment: Have you tried groupby-apply?

Comment: the original dataframe has single Ids entries (not repeated values). I do not see how groupby.apply can help me in this case :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function to be applied to each row:

```
def fn2(val, maxVal):
    tbl = []
    v1 = val // maxVal
    v2 = val % maxVal
    if v1:
        tbl.extend([maxVal] * v1)
    if v2:
        tbl.append(v2)
    return pd.Series(tbl)
```

In the above function *maxVal* is the maximal *value* to be set in
an output row.

And the actual processing can be done in a single (although chained)
instruction:

```
df.set_index('Id').Values.apply(fn2, maxVal=800).stack()\
    .rename('Values').astype(int)\
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Note that before *stack* some values are *NaN*, so the type was changed
to *float*. To change it back to *int*, I added *astype(int)*.

For your sample data the result is:

```
  Id Values
0  A    800
1  A    800
2  A    400
3  B    600
```

## Edit following your comment

If you have **only one** another column, you can "divide" *Values*
into chunks almost as you proposed:

```
df.set_index(['Id', 'AnotherCol']).Values.apply(fn2, maxVal=800)\
    .stack().rename('Values').astype(int)\
    .reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
```

The difference from your proposal is that the index level to drop is **2**
(not 0).

But if you have **more** such "additional" columns, a more natural way seems to:

- Calculate the *Series* of "divided *Values*" (I called it *vals*),
  with the index taken from source `Id` column.
- Drop "original" *Values* column from *df*.
- Merge it with *vals*. The merge keys are:

  - for *df* - `Id`,
  - for *vals* - the index.

So the code is:

```
vals = df.set_index(['Id']).Values.apply(fn2, maxVal=800)\
    .stack().rename('Values').astype(int)\
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
pd.merge(df.drop(columns=['Values']), vals,
    left_on='Id', right_index=True)
```

If you are unhappy about repeating index values, add `.reset_index(drop=True)`
to the last instruction.

Comment: Thank you for this great solution. My original `df` has more columns `anotherCol`, so my best guess to continue with the chain instruction will be like this:

`df.set_index(['Id','anotherCol']).Values.apply(fn2,maxVal=800).stack().rename('Values').astype(int).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index().drop(['level_1'], axis=1)`

@Valdi_Bo, would you do it differently?

Comment: just replicated your alternative, it was very helpful to see. I learnt one or two things from this... Thank you. In your last step I had to convert the `series` to a `df` before the merge:
`pd.merge(df.drop(columns=['Values']), vals.to_frame(), left_on='Id', right_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

This quick solution should give the required results, the code still needs optimization

```
max_val = 800

def split_x (x):
  lst=[]
  while x > max_val:
    x=x-max_val
    lst.append(max_val)
  if x != 0:
    lst.append(x)
  return lst

data = {'id':['A', 'B'],
        'value':[2000,600]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_new=pd.DataFrame({'id':[],'value':[]})

for i in range(len(df)):

  d=df.loc[i]['value']
  id=df.loc[i]['id']
  s=split_x(d)
  for i in range(len(s)):
    print (i,s[i])
    df_new=df_new.append({'id':id,'value':s[i]},ignore_index=True)

>>> df_new
  id  value
0  A  800.0
1  A  800.0
2  A  400.0
3  B  600.0
```

Comment: `d=df.loc[i]['value']` should surely be `d=df.loc[i, 'value']`?

Comment: @Dan both are same results

Comment: yes, but one is canonical pandas, the other is just a consequence of your first slice also returning a dataframe.  Use the comma.